# Почему не устанавливается phpmyadmin до конца?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Начинаю устанавливать phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

далее ставлю галочку при выборе apache2

выбираю настроить базу данных

при установки пароля просто ставлю галочку, он автоматически будет 
сгенерирован

и в конце выскакивает ошибка

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Что я делаю не так?

mysql работает, пароль от mysql "root"

mysql запускается в терминале при запуске mysql -uroot -proot

Вот ссылка на сайт https://losst.ru/ustanovka-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-na-nginx-ili-apache

Answer (score 0):

А попробуй пароль пустой оставить ;) 
Он тебе говорит

> Доступ заприщен для пользователя 'root'@'localhost' (использование пароля: НЕТ)

Если бы там был пароль или он бы не подходил он бы тебе написал в конце YES

Comment: Но я же могу зайти в mysql, mysql -u root -p root - работает, может mysql не нравится, что пароль к нему 'root'?

Comment: Блин ну тогда попробую создать другой пользователя дать ему root права и дай ему пароль, может это кстати какое то ограничение phpmyadmin ( но мало вероятно ) а ты кстати побывал сделать mysql -u root без пароля что говорит? - если пустит значит пароля нет.